# Cannot exchange AccessToken from Google API inside Docker container

Tags: docker, go, google-api, certificate, alpine-linux

I have a web app written in Go, use oauth2 (package `golang.org/x/oauth2`) to sign user in by Google (follow this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow).

When I test app on local, it works fine but when I deploy app and run inside a Docker container (base on `alpine:latest`, run binary file), it has an error: 
`Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Here is my code to exchange the accessToken:

```
ctx = context.Background()

config := &oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     config.GoogleClientId,
    ClientSecret: config.GoogleClientSecret,
    RedirectURL:  config.GoogleLoginRedirectUrl,
    Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
    Scopes:       []string{"email", "profile"},
}

accessToken, err := config.Exchange(ctx, req.Code)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())   // Error here
}
```

Comment: In the Docker image, install the CA bundle for your distribution. The package is typically called `ca-certificates`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not caused by Go but Alpine image.

Default Alpine image does not have certificates so the app cannot call to https address (this case is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token).

To fix this problem, install 2 packages `openssl` and `ca-certificates`. Example in Dockerfile:

```
apk add --no-cache ca-certificates openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the Google Issuing CA certificate to the trusted cert store of the docker image.

The Google CA cert is this https://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt .

More info on the certificate can be found from [here](https://pki.google.com/)

Then within the Dockerfile , you will need to do something like this

```
cp GIAG2.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/GIAG2.crt
update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: When I run `update-ca-certificates`, it displays warning `WARNING: ca-cert-GIAG2.pem does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping`

Comment: @RobinHuy , i think the full message that it gives is this                     
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
WARNING: GIAG2.pem does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping
1 added, 0 removed; done.                                                                                                                                  The certificate is added , did you try accessing the API again after this , i think it will work.

Comment: It's still not working. The full message is `WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
WARNING: ca-cert-GIAG2.pem does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping`. I copy file `GIAG2.crt` as your suggestion, but it's warning error at `ca-cert-GIAG2.pem`.