# Unable to access Google Cloud Storage from Google Kubernetes Engine using default service account and google cloud libraries

Tags: go, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts

I wrote an application that has a function to upload image through Google Kubernetes Engine using go lang. Everything else works fine, but I kept running into problems when I try to write image to Google Cloud Storage.

Here is my code in golang that actually uses the google storage api:

```
func putImage(imageURL string, image multipart.File) bool {
    fmt.Println("Putting into image location : " + imageURL)

    contextBackground := context.Background()
    storageClient, err := storage.NewClient(contextBackground)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No client.")
        return false
    }

    bucket := storageClient.Bucket("mytestbucketname")
    bucketWriter := bucket.Object(imageURL).NewWriter(contextBackground)
    bucketWriter.ContentType = "image/jpg"
    bucketWriter.CacheControl = "public, max-age=0"

    size, err := io.Copy(bucketWriter, image)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to put image")
        return false
    }

    fmt.Println(size)
    fmt.Println("Successfully put image")
    bucketWriter.Close()
    return true
}
```

The above function always returns true and size is always greater than 0. However, when I check the bucket, it does not actually have anything inside. So I researched around and realized that the default service account only has a read permission to Cloud Storage. Which is very weird because it should be returning false or size should be 0 or even outputting an error of permission denied.

The official cloud.google.com/go/storage API says Bucket() function returns a BucketHandle that does not actually perform any network operations, which makes sense as to why I was not getting permission denied error (?). And so I decided to check if I am actually getting anything from the Client or Bucket, just to see if the read permission is working. I added the following code :

```
attr, err := bucket.Attrs(contextBackground)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
fmt.Println("bucket name : " + attr.Name)
```

And at this point I started to get fatal errors that shuts down my application. The error I got when trying to retrieve bucket's attributes is this :

```
Get https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/mytestbucketname?alt=json&prettyPrint=false&projection=full: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

So I thought I need to add ca certificate to my image. But it just does not sound logical to me because if I was running my image in Google Kubernetes Engine and it was accessing my Google Cloud Storage, given that it already has a default service account with read permission, why would I need a certificate? I made a new cluster with version 1.12.8-gke.10 and made sure to disable issue client certificate and made sure I had read permission to Storage and still got the same error. And I added this line to my docker file and still got the same error:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

I've been at it for two days and now I'm running out of ideas. My question is what am I doing wrong that keeps giving me "x.509 certificate signed by unknown authority" error when trying to access the Storage bucket attributes from Kubernetes Engine when I am using default permission? Technically getting bucket attributes is just a read function, which I am supposed to be able to do with default permission right? If anyone has any ideas or has ever ran into the same problem, please give me some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, just leaving this here if anyone ever runs into this problem too. It was my mistake of being very careless, but after reading this question :

[Cannot exchange AccessToken from Google API inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341878/cannot-exchange-accesstoken-from-google-api-inside-docker-container/52343054)

I was able to narrow it down to a certificate problem. It was actually because I did not install the ca-certificate properly. Because I was using multi stage build in my docker file, I misplaced this line of code :

```
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

After placing it correctly it worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default cluster service account, you need to make sure the cluster has [sufficient scopes to write to storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#applications). By [default](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--scopes), GKE clusters only have the read scope which blocks write attempts to GCS buckets.

> gke-default:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append

Without the write scope enabled, regardless of the credentials, you won't be able to write to buckets.

> Note: You can use the access token only for scopes that you specified when you created the instance. For example, if the instance has been granted only the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/storage-full scope for Google Cloud Storage, then it can't use the access token to make a request to BigQuery.

If you want to bypass scopes, create a custom service account for the application, download the JWT token and mount these credentials directly into your code. This is the [recommended method to authenticate your application](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform) against Google APIs

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear. I meant to ask, why am I receiving an error when I am trying to get bucket attributes when I am using default permission? Technically getting bucket attributes is just a read function, which I am supposed to be able to do with default permission right?

Comment: Something is going wrong with the default node service account getting mounted. The token is either expired or not being mounted into the request properly. It is best practice to mount your credentials directly into the application for the call (see the last link in my answer)

Comment: Thanks for replying Patrick. I've tried the recommended method to authenticate as well, but no luck unfortunately, was getting the same error :/ I believe my service account is mounted correctly, but I'm not sure if token is expired or not. Is there any way I can check that? Like maybe I can log something from my image to see the service account's token status?

Comment: I would recommend to just generate a new token from the service accounts page and use that.

Comment: I have tested out running it on localhost, and it actually works without any problem. I was able to get the name of the service account I was using. However it still doesn't work on Google Kubernetes Engine. It makes sens that it works on my local machine as I was singed in through gcloud. Now I assume this means that somehow the authentication is off inside the cluster right? But how can that be? and how can I actually reset the authentication?

Comment: Also, I did actually try to generate a new token from service account page and generate a key and followed the steps. However I was getting the same error. I feel like it has something to do with authenticating.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for trying to help! I figured it out. It was my careless mistake!

Comment: Could you let us know what it was in case others have the same issue?

Comment: Of course Patrick, I answered my own question. But basically it was because I misplaced adding ca certificate to my image. Because I was using multi stage build in my dockerfile, the misplacing the adding of certificate caused my image to have to certificate and therefore unable to make https API calls to Google!